# Nested query WHERE procedure code IN and AND

Tags: sql, nested

Would like to take the following Query and alter it so that it brings back ONLY records where each patient (based on MRN) has BOTH ProcedureCodeList IN ('115-1','117-1','311-1') AND ProcedureCodeList = '119-103'

```
 SELECT P.SiteID, O.ProcedureCodeList, P.MRN, PINFO.LastName, PINFO.FirstName, PINFO.[State] AS Species, PINFO.City AS Breed, O.ProcedureDescList, RF.FieldName, RF.FieldValue, R.ContentText
, R.LastSignDate

FROM ReportFinding RF

INNER JOIN Report R
ON RF.ReportID = R.ReportID
INNER JOIN [Order] O
ON R.ReportID = O.ReportID
INNER JOIN Visit V
ON O.VisitID = V.VisitID
INNER JOIN Patient P
ON P.PatientID = V.PatientID
INNER JOIN PersonalInfo PINFO
ON P.PersonalInfoID = PINFO.PersonalInfoID

WHERE
O.ProcedureCodeList IN ('115-1','117-1','119-103')

ORDER BY R.LastSignDate DESC
```

Comment: Isn't has BOTH ProcedureCodeList IN ('115-1','117-1','311-1') AND ProcedureCodeList = '119-103' the same as ProcedureCodeList = '119-103'..... I think you might have a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve this.  One way is to create two subqueries  and join them on the MRN.

```
SELECT a.SiteID, a.ProcedureCodeList, a.MRN, a.LastName, a.FirstName, a.Species, a.Breed, a.ProcedureDescList, a.FieldName, a.FieldValue, a.ContentText, a.LastSignDate
FROM 
(SELECT P.SiteID, O.ProcedureCodeList, P.MRN, PINFO.LastName, PINFO.FirstName, PINFO.[State] AS Species, PINFO.City AS Breed, O.ProcedureDescList, RF.FieldName, RF.FieldValue, R.ContentText, R.LastSignDate
FROM ReportFinding RF
INNER JOIN Report R ON RF.ReportID = R.ReportID
INNER JOIN [Order] O ON R.ReportID = O.ReportID
INNER JOIN Visit V ON O.VisitID = V.VisitID
INNER JOIN Patient P ON P.PatientID = V.PatientID
INNER JOIN PersonalInfo PINFO ON P.PersonalInfoID = PINFO.PersonalInfoID
WHERE O.ProcedureCodeList IN ('115-1','117-1','119-103')) as a
JOIN 
(SELECT P.MRN
FROM [Order]
INNER JOIN Visit V ON O.VisitID = V.VisitID
INNER JOIN Patient P ON P.PatientID = V.PatientID
WHERE O.ProcedureCodeList = '119-103') as b ON a.MRN = b.MRN
ORDER BY a.LastSignDate
```

The PersonalInfo table is not needed in the second query.  I don't think ReportFinding and Report are either, based on your JOINs.  It depends on what these tables are actually doing.

Another way starts with the original query and adds the following to the WHERE clause (before the ORDER BY):

```
AND P.MRN IN
(SELECT P.MRN
FROM [Order]
INNER JOIN Visit V ON O.VisitID = V.VisitID
INNER JOIN Patient P ON P.PatientID = V.PatientID
WHERE O.ProcedureCodeList = '119-103')
```

I would look at the execution plans of both solutions to know which is the better one in this case.

Comment: This ultimately does what I need it to do, thank you. The problem I ran into was that, in my original thought process, I would add in a WHERE clause on the original query WHERE r.ContentText Like '%free air%'. However, I forgot that the 119-3 does not have a report, so when I run the query as above, it does not list out the rows where there are 119-3. Though it does, ultimately show me my requests as I kind of need them. So I *think* this will suffice.